# Modal View controllers vs Orientation in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, modalviewcontroller

I'm presenting modal ViewController having ModalPresentationStyle set to UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext to have parent view on the background. The thing that really confuses me is when I'm trying to change iPad orientation, modal view is resized correctly while parent controller keeps original orientation.

The question is can I forward orientation change notifications to parent controller, or to force it to re-layout with new orientation?

Answer (score 0):

You should notify your parent controller about orientation change. This behaviour changed in ios5 or similar. For example:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("changeOrientation", null);
```

This is a notification you should send from the modal controller when its orientation changes. Parent controller should subscribe to this notification BEFORE showing modal controller or in ViewDidAppear method.

```
this.orientationObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("changeOrientation", HandleRotation);
```

... and unsubscribe after modal controller is hidden or in the ViewWillDisappear method (if subscribed in ViewDidAppear).

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (this.orientationObserver);
```

The good thing about this approach as there is no direct refence to the parent controller in the modal controller and vice-versa.

Comment: I don't see how will it help me to change parent controller orientation... I can fire event or something from modal controller when orientation is changed. What I'm trying to figure out is how to make parent controller to re-layout subview automatically